# Streaming Audio in Java

Tags: java, android, streaming, voice-recording

I have been writing an application where I record the voice on android device and send it to PC using Sockets (UDP). `Problem I'm facing is how to pass incoming data (byte[]) to speaker?`

My Current implementation is just creating Speaker instances each time when data is received. Which is making the voice a bit jerky. It looks a very common thing but I couldn't manage to figure it out.

Here is my code that is receiving data and sending it to speaker

```
while (true) {
    final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    // Reading data from socket - UDP
    serverSocket.receive(packet);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Sending data to speaker in separate thread
            SpeakerManager.toSpeaker(packet.getData());
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Here is the code that plays voice on speaker

```
private static final AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(Common.SAMPLE_RATE, 16, 1, true, false);

public static void toSpeaker(byte soundbytes[]) {
    try {
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        try (SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo)) {
            sourceDataLine.open(format);
            FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) sourceDataLine.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            volumeControl.setValue(6.0f);
            sourceDataLine.start();
            sourceDataLine.write(soundbytes, 0, soundbytes.length);
            sourceDataLine.drain();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not working in speakers...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that voice is recorded just fine, by collecting the multiple incoming data to a large buffer and play it together. But I want to have continuous voice. I also have to do the same in reverse direction.

I can imagine a way to bind speaker with input steam, and it keep playing voice when ever it get data on socket. But don't know how to do that.

I'd like to emphasize that want to transfer voice in realtime, so any solution with saving and sending won't be suitable for me.

Comment: You may try using a ByteArrayOutputStream with a predefined (and larger) byte[], and then pass it on to write method. This way you will probably have a buffer of bytes rather than breakup data. ByteBuffer is another option.
P.S. How are you planning to keep the order of packets intact? UDP does not guarantee packet ordering.